# Reduce heavy noise in text (driver license) using OpenCV to OCR later?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I already search multiple questions and most of them are just light noise, or text is much bigger than noise. But in my case, noise is really big.

I already remove the background and binarizing the image, try some denoising methods and so far adaptiveThreshold is the most promising.

But still a lot of noise in the right of the image.

Any approach to solving this problem, even outside OpenCV is welcome.

Here is the input image:

[image]

Here is the output image:

[image]

Hear is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

src = cv2.imread("0TEST.JPG")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#remove background
alpha = 3.0
beta = -200
new = alpha * gray + beta
new = np.clip(new, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(new, (3, 3), 0)

th1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

#Denoising
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(blur, None, 3, 7, 21)

cv2.imshow("OUTPUT", dst)

k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:  # wait for ESC key to exit, ESC represented as ASCII code 27 in decimal
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'):  # wait for 's' key to save and exit
    cv2.imwrite('0OUTPUT.png', dst)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your results look quite good to me considering the problem isn't some form of compression noise, but rather large ink splotches on the photographed page. I don't see a way your program will remove such a large black dot and not a tiny dash in the writing.

Comment: In your processed image - the dots after the numerals 1. 2. 3. are all removed because they are thought to be noise. Is this acceptable? In English language an algorithm designed to remove noise of this magnitude will also remove dots like the one above 'i' or 'j' however a decent OCR system will still recognize j even without the dot. what is the scenrio in japanese?